# Est-ce que le sens de "rouler des pelles" change par région en France?

Tags: argot, france

Comme dit la question. C'est une expression française, ça signifie "embrasser avec la langue", mais est-ce partout la même chose? Est-ce que l'expression prend un autre sens (comme "faire une gaffe") ailleurs?

Comment: ce serait plutôt l'expression "prendre un râteau" qui serait assimilé à avoir fait une gaffe, dans le même esprit... :)

Comment: @Random J'aime qu'il y aie une formule "[verbe] + [article] + [outil de jardin]" dans l'argot.

Comment: pour info, ça se dit en Belgique aussi. Quelqu'un sait-il pour le Québec ?

Comment: @radouxju Pas que je sache (et j'y suis), mais mon expérience n'est peut-être pas représentative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ça a la même signification partout en France.

Comment: Les réponses sans justification, explication ou référence sont généralement mal perçues. [Le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouler_une_pelle) est en tout cas d'accord et ne propose que cette définition.